# Data Streaming - Debezium MySQL Connector Configuration to stream CDC to kafka Topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm setting up data streaming pipeline with Kafka, Debezium MySQL Connector and MySQL. When the data is inserted into MySQL, the Debezium MySQL Connector(CDC) need to push the data to Kafka topic  and consumer application will do ETL.

Followed these steps for installation and configuration:

1. Kafka through - **https://kafka.apache.org/downloads** .Binary downloads : Scala 2.13  - kafka_2.13-3.4.0.tgz (asc, sha512).
   Kafka version - 3.4.0
2. Debezium MySQL connector - **https://debezium.io/releases/2.1/**. Debezium - 2.1.1
3. Created two topics **stream** and **history**
4. I have placed Debezium MySQL Connector inside **connector** folder which is present inside this path **/home/divum/kafka-all/kafka_2.13-3.4.0**.

5.Created a **connect-debezium-mysql.properties** file inside /config folder and add these inside the file:

```
name=etl-connector

connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector

#connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mysql

tasks.max=1

database.hostname=localhost

database.port=3306

database.user=root

database.password=iphone21

topic.prefix=stream

database.server.id=4816

database.include.list=etl

table.include.list=.*

column.include.list=.*

include.schema.changes=false

database.server.name=mysql

tombstones.on.delete=false

database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

database.history.kafka.topic=history

type here
```

6. Added the **plugin.path** inside a file **connect-standalone.properties** which is present inside **/config** folder.

```
plugin.path=/home/divum/kafka-all/kafka_2.13-3.4.0/connector/debezium-connector-mysql
```

7. Started the Kafka using these 3 commands:

```
1)bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
2)bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
3)bin/connect-standalone.sh ./config/connect-standalone.properties ./config/connect-debezium-mysql.properties
```

8. After using third command from 7th point getting this error:
   [Please check this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0df8l.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0df8l.png)

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector, available connectors are: PluginDesc
```

Comment: You need to place the connector extracted inside the plugin directory (instead of kafka root), can you share the full path?

Comment: @RonakJain  In this is the folder **/home/divum/kafka-all/kafka_2.13-3.4.0/connector** I have placed my **debezium-connector-mysql** and the full path is like this **/home/divum/kafka-all/kafka_2.13-3.4.0/connector/debezium-connector-mysql**

Comment: You shouldn't put connectors in the same path as Kafka itself, as this causes other classpath conflicts. Try instead moving the debezium folder and use just `plugin.path=/home/divum/kafka-connect-plugins`, for example (inside this folder, put the debezium connector folder)

Comment: @OneCricketeer My path is like this plugin.path=/home/divum/kafka-connect-plugins/debezium-connector-mysql still getting same error, check step 8

Comment: 1) Use `connect-distributed.sh` + properties rather than standalone 2) After you start the server, use `GET /connector-plugins` API endpoint and see if the Debezium plugin actually got loaded. Then debug from there by looking at startup logs to see if it was actually scanned or not. Only after you see the connector in that API response, should you load your connector config.

Comment: @BhuvaneshkumarJ Path should be till connector only

Comment: Check the reference link in my answer for example directory structure

Comment: @RonakJain Then I can use like this **plugin.path=/home/divum/kafka-connect-plugins** ? I'm editing this file **connect-standalone.properties**.

Comment: Yes you can, just put the connector parent directory inside it, and check if the connector is loaded as suggested by @OneCricketeer

Comment: @OneCricketeer  I'm not able to get your point.

Comment: @RonakJain Please check this like as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75445470/failed-to-find-any-class-that-implements-connector-and-which-name-matches-io-deb

Comment: My point is that your error is saying that the plugin doesn't exist. Kafka Connect starts an HTTP server with an endpoint where you can see all plugins that are installed before you ever post a configuration where you're currently seeing your error. I'm saying that you should debug more