# Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector, available connectors are

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Setting up Data Streaming Pipeline using Kafka, MySQL and Debezium. I'm this version of Kafka - 3.4.0, MySQL - 8, Debezium - 2.2.1, Java - 11. **AIM : I want to capture all CDC from MySQL and stream the data to Kafka Topics.**

If have followed these steps:

1. Downloaded Kafka - 3.4.0 and extracted and kept in this path : /home/divum/kafka-all/kafka_2.13-3.4.0
2. Downloaded Debezium - 2.2.1 and extracted it. This is the path for it path : /usr/local/share/kafka/plugins/debezium-connector-mysql
3. Added this line **plugin.path=/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins/debezium-connector-mysql** in file **connect-distributed.properties** which is present inside this path : **/home/divum/kafka-all/kafka_2.13-3.4.0/config**.
4. And I have MySql and Debezium Configuration like the below. Enabled binary logs as well. The file name is connector-config.json, which is present in this path **/home/divum/kafka-all/kafka_2.13-3.4.0**.

```
{  "name": "etl-connector",
  "config": {

"connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",    
"tasks.max": 1,
    "database.hostname": "localhost",
    "database.port": 3306,
    "database.user": "root",
    "database.password": "iphone21",
    "topic.prefix": "stream",
    "database.server.id": 4816,
    "database.include.list": "etl",
    "table.include.list": ".*",
    "column.include.list": ".*",
    "include.schema.changes": false,
    "database.server.name": "mysql",
    "tombstones.on.delete": false,
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "history",

"plugin.path":"/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins/debezium-connector-mysql"

  }
}
```

5. I'm using this command for starting the broker, zookeeper, and connector.

```
Zookeeper -  bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
Kafka Broker - bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
Connector - bin/connect-distributed.sh ./config/connect-distributed.properties
```

6. Checking the connector-plugins with **curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8083/connector-plugins'**. Getting the below output.

```
[
    {
        "class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector",
        "type": "source",
        "version": "3.4.0"
    },
    {
        "class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector",
        "type": "source",
        "version": "3.4.0"
    },
    {
        "class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector",
        "type": "source",
        "version": "3.4.0"
    }
]
```

7. Trying to start the connector with this command ** curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @connector-config.json http://localhost:8083/connectors** and getting below error. It's saying like this **io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector** Class is not available.

```
{"error_code":500,"message":"Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector, available connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector', version='3.4.0', encodedVersion=3.4.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}"}
```

8. Command Used : **bin/connect-distributed.sh ./config/connect-distributed.properties **. Getting this logs.
   [image: image-1]
   [image: image-2]
   [image: image-3]
   [image: image-4]
   [image: iamge-5]
   [image: image-6]
9. Plugin scan logs:
   [image: 1]
   [image: 2]
   [image: 3]
   [image: 4]
   [image: 5]
   [image: 6]

I'm trying with setup for past few days not able to do it. What was the cause of this error? Any idea how to solve it?

Is there any open source alternative is there for Debezium?

Comment: Debezium is open source only, you can try Maxwell (it runs as standalone app, not as kafka connector) the deployment is easier, but it's for Mysql only.

Comment: Please show your log output after running `connect-distributed.sh`

Comment: @OneCricketeer I will edit and add in the above question.

Comment: You've cut off the part where it actually scans for plugins

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have added plugin scan logs

Comment: @OneCricketeer When I changed **connector.class** from **io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector** to **io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector** not getting the error which I have mentioned in Step - 7. But facing issue like this **org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/etl**

Comment: Confluent doesn't include any database drivers. Go to mysql website to download it. Debezium/CDC connectors are better than JDBC though... Are you not able to use [Debezium Server](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/operations/debezium-server.html) (with Kafka sink)?

Comment: I am not sure of this helps but I spent almost a whole day troubleshooting the same error. I even tried different versions of Debezium MySQL Connectors without positive results. What works for me was moving the whole extracted debezium mysql connector directory to `<kafka_installation_path>/libs`. `libs` is where Kafka put all connectors JARs by default.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that the debezium connector is not being loaded. When you run a GET on `/connector-plugins`, you should see a debezium entry.

After Step 2, try to move the debezium artifact (which is probably a jar), into the Kafka plugin directory, instead of changing the `plugin.path` as in step 3. Check the following [article](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/self-managed/install.html#install-connector-manually) from Confluent.

When you get to step 6, you need to register the connector by making a `POST` request at `http://localhost:8083/connectors` with the following payload:

```json
{
    "name": "<some-unique-name>",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
        "database.hostname": "<>",
        "database.port": "<>",
        "database.user": "<>",
        "database.password": "<>",
        "database.server.name": "<>",
        "database.server.id": <>,
        "database.include.list": "<>",
        "table.include.list": "<>",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "<kafka-url>",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "<result-topic-name>",
        "topics": "<result-topic-name>"
    }
}
```

Follow [the documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/debezium-mysql-source/current/mysql_source_connector_config.html#debezium-mysql-source-connector-configuration-properties) for a proper setup.

Comment: In step 6 I'm able to see the entry, that is fine right?

Comment: Have a look at the update

Comment: From the linked post `/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins` isn't the "kafka installation directory". Plugins can be placed anywhere on disk. I've personally put them in `/opt` or `/tmp` for testing and updated `plugin.path` accordingly

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution after experimenting multiple configurations. Posting the solution finally worked.

1. Use Java - 11
2. Just changing the **connector.class** from this **io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector** to **io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector**.

```
    {
      "name": "etl-connector",
      "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "tasks.max": 1,
        "database.hostname": "localhost",
        "database.port": 3306,
        "database.user": "root",
        "database.password": "iphone21",
        "topic.prefix": "stream",
        "database.server.id": 4816,
        "database.include.list": "etl",
        "table.include.list": ".*",
        "column.include.list": ".*",
        "include.schema.changes": false,
        "database.server.name": "mysql",
        "tombstones.on.delete": false,
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "history",
        "plugin.path": "/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins/debezium-connector-mysql"
      }
    }
```

3. The issue is with my plugin path, just add the path like this:

   nano ./config/connect-distributed.properties

   plugin.path=<path/of-your-debezium/*>

   Eg : plugin.path=/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins/debezium-connector-mysql/*
4. Once plugin path is added, please verify it after running the below command.

   bin/connect-distributed.sh ./config/connect-distributed.properties
5. Go through the INFO logs, it should show the path which you have used for the configuration.

   jvm.classpath=<path/of-your-debezium/*>

After Step - 5 if you able to start the connectors with **curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @connector-config.json http://localhost:8083/connectors** then step -6,7 are not required.

6. If same issue then add **CLASSPATH** in your **.bashrc**

   nano ~/.bashrc

   export CLASSPATH=<path/of-your-debezium/*>

   Eg : export CLASSPATH=/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins/debezium-connector-mysql/*

   source ~/.bashrc
7. Once everything is added just kill the existing terminal, stop the kafka connector and start it again or restart it in the new terminal. Because in existing won't reload the new configuration. Then everything will work fine.

Comment: Downvote because this doesn't actually solve your error with finding the Debezium connector, and many of these configuration values aren't available for JDBC Sink

Comment: @OneCricketeer Please have a up vote, I did the same and got the output.

Comment: Adding Debezium to the classpath doesn't do anything for JDBC connector from Confluent... JDBC connector may give you data, but it's not the same thing, or fixing the error you originally posed about